# Bootstrap 4 - Fluid Height Layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a website that is using Bootstrap 4. I'm trying to create a layout that takes up the full height of the screen. I thought the new "flex" grid approach in Bootstrap 4 was supposed to support this. Perhaps I'm doing it incorrectly? At this time, the height of my app only fills as much as is needed by the content. At this time, as shown in this [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/FzkcOmC4bO), the entire height of the available area isn't filled. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><h2>My Name</h2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3" style="background-color:#fff;">
          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            <div>Users</div>
          </div>

          <div class="text-center" style="color:orange;">
            <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
            <div>Files</div>
          </div>

          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i>
            <div>Containers</div>
          </div>

          <hr>

          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
            <div>Feedback</div>
          </div>      

          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
            <div>Help</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-9" style="background-color:#eee;">
          <div>item 1</div>
          <div>item 2</div>
          <div>item 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="col-9" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      [main content goes here]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I use the entire height of the screen while leveraging the flex grid in Bootstrap 4?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought the new "flex" grid approach in Bootstrap 4 was supposed to
>   support this.

It does, and here is a start, where we first need to give the container a height, so I added this rule:

```
.container-fluid {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Then I added the classes `d-flex flex-column` to the `<div class="container-fluid">` element, making them column items so we can use *flex-grow* to *stretch* them so they fill their parent's height.

And finally, added `col` to the 2nd/last `<div class="row">` element, and with that, it get `flex-grow: 1`, to fill the space left.

*The 2nd/last `row` also has an inner `row`, having a `col-3` element, which also need to be setup similar, though as I don't know how these should wrap etc., I left those for you to set up yourself. When you do, a great tip is to give different background colors, or borders, to ancestors/siblings, and you will see how they behave.*

[Update bootply](https://www.bootply.com/HDLC1Y7HLD)

Stack snippet

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><h2>My Name</h2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row col">
    <div class="col-3 ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3" style="background-color:#fff;">
          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
            <div>Users</div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="text-center" style="color:orange;">
            <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
            <div>Files</div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i>
            <div>Containers</div>
          </div>

          <hr>

          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
            <div>Feedback</div>
          </div>      
      
          <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
            <div>Help</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-9" style="background-color:#eee;">
          <div>item 1</div>
          <div>item 2</div>
          <div>item 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
    
    <div class="col-9" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      [main content goes here]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column" style="height:100vh; padding:0px; background-image:url('images/header_bg_1.jpg'); background-size:cover; ">
```

I set the height to 100vh and added the flex classes.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I posted 8 months earlier, so why post the same one more time?

Comment: This is a bit simplified answer for a shortcut so, i went for Ron's answer. :)